# How to create flow chart type drag and drop in C#

Tags: c#, flowchart

I'm new in C# and want to create a drag and drop program for kids to learn program.
I have learned about drag and drop in C# but I got stuck in creating conditional and if-else conditions in drag and drop.

What I want is that if user drag while button from control and after that if inside while than while loop cover the if else condition which looks like if-else is child of while loop.
And I want some guide how can I convert that flow chart in C language code.

Please take a look in these images so you can understand what I want actually.

Suppose user drag while loop from control than it should look like this:
[image]

As you can see while loop has a bottom border like its boundaries when I drag if-else condition inside it it becomes like this:

[image]

As you can if I put other controls inside if-else condition it will automatically adjust itself.

I want functionality like this.

What I have done:-

**1. I have make program of simple drag and drop.**

**2. I'm using onMouseDown listener in every image, means that if there is 40 image for drag and drop than I have create 40 onMouseDown methods in C#, which I thought is not a good way.**

If you know what should i do to create functionality like this please tell me and also tell best way to convert that flow chart in c Code.

You can check the software that have same functionality to understand more better what I want if you did not understand it till.
here is the link:
http://www.roboroboglobal.com/support/download.html

Comment: Id recommend showing a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with some code if you could.

Comment: I suggest u to rather add the code you tried which didn't work..Also narrow down your post to specify only the problem and requirement .. Hope u understand :)

Comment: As far as i understand you can drag objects to connect with each other, buy you can't move the if-block into the while block? Check mouse cords, compare with element list in frame, check if mouse is within the boundary box of any of these elements. If so check wether tha block can hold another block within it. If true --> adjust size of container which your object was dragged into or of dragged object. If false define your desired behaviour.
Lastly: Show some code!!

Comment: @zack raiyan, my drag and drop code is working fine but I dont understand the logic of nested block like the images in the code :(

Comment: Everything in your image , are they all images ?

Comment: I mean as u said a user can drag-drop , are they all images ? Do u want to combine images or combine codes ?

Comment: @zackraiyan, They are images in my case

Comment: Then u need to combine two images right ?

Comment: may be? I don't know what to do, to get the same result as above images :(

Comment: Looks like MIT Scratch